# Does a service principal allow for different levels of access dependent on the user of the application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This is a super rookie question, so apologies in advance. I'm going to make a number of assumptions in my question, so please don't hesitate in correcting me if any are wrong.

Within Azure, you can set up Azure AD security groups. This is a way of authenticating users and the permissions they have within Azure. For example, I could create a group called "Storage Account A" which would give users in the group permission to read/write into the containers within Storage Account A.

Now, I am looking to build an Excel-based application that will need to interact with Azure Blob Storage APIs. However, the specific containers/permissions it should speak to will depend on the user in question (i.e. user A should only be able to access container A, user B should only be able to access container A and container B). So ultimately, I'm looking to delegate specific Azure access to my application, as well as authenticate users based on their AD group membership.

For this sort of use-case, is the best authorization/authentication route to go down the Service Application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give certain users in an AAD group access to certain containers, <del>the only way to do this is by enabling "hierarchical namespace" upon creation of the storage account effectively turning your storage account into a Data Lake Storage Gen2.</del> you can [use Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-an-azure-built-in-role) as pointed out by Mullins. If you need to give group-based permissions on file level, the only way to do this is by enabling "hierarchical namespace" upon creation of the storage account effectively turning your storage account into a Data Lake Storage Gen2. This will open up the possibility to use [ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control) which in turn give you the possibility to assign read/write access for certain AAD groups on certain containers.

So suppose you have a Data Lake Storage Gen2 "mylake" with two containers, *con-a* and *con-b*. Let's also suppose you want to give only users who are member of the AAD group "CONTAINER_A" with the object ID "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef" read, write and execute access on con-a. You can do so by running the az CLI command

```
az storage fs access set --acl "user::---,group:01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef:rwx,other::---" -p . -f con-a --account-name mylake --auth-mode login
```

Suppose next a user is only member of the "CONTAINER_A" AAD group and this group has Azure RBAC *Contributor* role assigned on mylake. This user can log in and list all directories in *con-a* running

```
az storage fs directory list -f con-a --account-name mylake --auth-mode login
```

which will output all directories in this container (if there are any), but this command

```
az storage fs directory list -f con-b --account-name mylake --auth-mode login
```

will fail with the message

```
(AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

**Edit:**

What you will indeed need if you want to write a client application that accesses the storage account is an **App Registration**. Creating this in AAD will in turn automatically also create a service principal, but you shouldn't care much about it in your case. The app registration should be configured with *delegated permissions* as it creates access tokens on behalf of the logged in user. There is a good overview about the necessary steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet), depending on the language you write your client code in and how the client behaves (e.g. if it's possible to open the default browser to let users login at *login.microsoftonline.com*) you may have to adopt the flow a little.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Very helpful.

How does this dovetail with the Service Principal? Let's say that user 1 only has access to th "CONTAINER_A" AAD group, but user 2 has access to "CONTAINER_A" and "CONTAINER_B" AAD groups. Can the service principal accommodate these two different types of access within the same application?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need a service principal at all in this scenario. It's sufficient when your users (user principals) are in the different AAD groups and each group gets the according rights for the different containers. If user 2 is member of both groups, "CONTAINER_A" and "CONTAINER_B", then he will be able to access both containers.

Comment: I suppose it's because I'm also looking to try and provide some authorisation to the application that it can act on the user's behalf in terms of the API calls it will be making to blob storage. Does a Service Principal not offer up that sort of authorization as well as access control?

Comment: I think what you mean is an app registration. I added that to my answer, registering an app registration makes it possible to create access tokens the client can use to authenticate itself to the storage account leveraging the user's permission on the storage account.

Comment: Thanks Simon. One last thing; you say that you can only set permissions at the container level using an ACL. However, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal it says that an RBAC role can be set to have a resource scope of an individual container?

Comment: You are absolutely right, my mistake, I edited it. This makes large parts of my answer obsolete for your case :)